# Check id of foreign key object

Tags: django, django-models, django-middleware

Im trying to write a function to check that the user has correct member category.

My models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Membercategory(models.Model):
    membercatname = models.CharField(max_length=200)  


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobilephone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)  
    membercategory = models.ForeignKey(Membercategory, blank=True, null=True)
```

My user-check middleware:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings

class UserCheckMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):

        invalid_user_path = settings.INVALID_USER_URL

        if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.user.is_staff:

            if not request.user.profile.membercategory(id=426):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(invalid_user_path)
        else:
            return
```

The error I get is: `Membercategory object is not callable`

How should I do the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as the error says, Django model instances are not callable. You just want a simple comparison to the ID:

```
if request.user.profile.membercategory_id != 426:
```